# Prove any sublinear $p:X\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $p(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in X$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

If $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is a complex normed vector space, $p:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is sublinear iff

1. $p(\alpha x)=|\alpha|p(x)$ and
2. $p(x+y)\le p(x)+p(y)$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $x,y\in X$.

I want to prove that any sublinear $p:X\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $p(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in X$, which should be quite easy but I cannot see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $x\in X$, by the first property:
$$p(-x)=p(-1x)=|-1|p(x)=p(x)$$ So, by the second property $$p(0)=p(x+(-x))\le p(x)+p(-x)=2p(x)\tag{1}$$ for any $x\in X$. In particular $(1)$ holds for $x=0$ (note that $X$ as a normed vector space contains an element that can be identified as the $0$ vector) giving $$p(0)\le 2p(0) \iff 0\le p(0) \tag{2}$$ Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together: $$0\le p(0)\le 2p(x)\implies 0\le p(x), \qquad \forall x\in X$$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that
$$
 p(0) = p(0 \cdot 0) = 0 \cdot p(0) = 0.
$$
and for every $x \in X$
$$
 p(-x) = p((-1)x) = |-1| \ p(x) = p(x).
$$
It follows that for every $x \in X$
$$
 0 
 = p(0)
 = p(x - x)
 \leq p(x)+p(-x)
 = p(x)+p(x)
 = 2p(x),
$$
so $0 \leq p(x)$.

Comment: Why is $p(-x) = -p(x)$? Doesn’t this contradict the statement if $p \neq 0$?

Comment: Sorry. Just edited it.

Comment: How does $p(0)+p(-x)=p(x)+p(x)$?

Comment: @user3482534 sorry. Now it is correct.